# Windows Defender Security Center

Tags: notification-area, windows-defender, windows-10-v1703

after the creator update I have an annoying problem regarding the windows defender security center and the relative notification.

I have some files that defender marks as trojan / virus, they are indeed threat but I need them in my computer; So after the scan and notification I checked the option "Allow on device" and then used the button "Start Actions".

Windows defender then shows a popup "Allow Threats" which I confirm but nothing change and I still got the icon with the red icon "x".

[image]

What can I do to remove this annoying notification (the threats are actually in in "Allowed Threats" area.

Comment: I am unsure as to why you would want to keep 3 Trojans on your PC that allow more viruses & hackers access your PC?

Comment: I do not see any problem in that. I'm fully aware about them, they are php and js script that cannot be used and I keep it for testing purpose. but this is irrelevant to the request :)

Comment: Add an exception for those threats simply allowing them doesn't do that

Comment: yeah, they already are in "allowed threats" but the notification and red alter remains...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the new UI of Windows Defender Security Center.

I solved the issue, allowing the items using the old interface of Windows defender.

To do that:

- Open "MSASCui.exe" located in "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\"
- Wait few minutes before the old Win Defender starts, then allow the threats and apply.
- Wait until the process ends

Now everything works fine both in the old and in the new interface / taskbar.

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. I had the same problem. The warning kept showing up after selecting "Allow threat" in the new Defender interface, but using the old interface the way you described made the notification go away.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I confirm that to solve red cross on Windows defender security center icon you need to open manually Windows Defender antivirus and solve the conflict of false positive virus like Marcx said. The worry is that on 13th of March 2018 this mistake is not solved yet and the doubt of efficiency of this antivirus exists.

Comment: This should be a comment.